# Navigation menu that only follows screen vertically not horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, position

You can see my problem on the image here:

[image]

When I minimized my website, I discovered that my contents flows over my navigation when I use the vertical scroll bar. 
I know I could just use a z-index to make it go behind. But I want to be able to scroll to the right and see the rest of the page to the right, without scrolling the "content".

Right now, this is only run locally. So I can't give you a link to the page.

Here's the stripped HTML:

```
<div id="main-wrapper">
<div id="menu-wrapper">
    <div id="logo">
        <a href="index.html">
        </a>
    </div>
    <div id="nav">
    </div>
</div>
<div id="content-wrapper">
    <div id="sub-content">
    </div>
</div>
```

And the CSS for the menu and content area:

```
#menu-wrapper 
{
position: fixed;
width: 223px;
height: 100%;
}

#content-wrapper 
{
width: 698px;
min-height: 500px;
position: absolute;
left: 223px;
top: 41px;
}
```

I hope that you can help me out, and please let me know if you need any more information

Comment: What's your css on #main-wrapper?

Comment: I haven't assigned any styling to it. The problems lies in there?

Comment: Nope. I'll post an answer in a second.

Comment: Okay, that sounds brilliant Dragos. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: fixed` will make your ellement 'follow' you on page that's why the text is overlapping your left bar.

Anyway, the following should work as you want:

```
#menu-wrapper {
    position: fixed;
    width: 223px;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 999;
}

#content-wrapper {
    width: 698px;
    min-height: 500px;
    padding-top: 41px;
    margin-left: 223px;
}
```

I would still set that z-index in case the user has javascript disabled. Let the content hide under the menu. Best solution in worst case scenario.

Make sure you have jquery loaded. If not, add this into your header:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
```

Now add this just before `</body>`:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        $('#menu-wrapper').css({'position' : 'absolute', 'top': $(window).scrollTop()});
    });
});
```

Here is a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j7HaN/6/) for better demonstration.

Comment: Yeah, I knew that.
But since the menu-wrapper is the navigation. I want it to continue down the page when I scroll down. So I need to use the position:fixed.

Comment: I guess I'll just need to use the z-index to make the content go behind and live with it.

Comment: So basically, you say that you would like your menu to follow you vertically, but not horizontally. Give me a few mins. I think I've got what you've meant now.

Comment: Yes, exactly. Otherwise just ask. :)

Comment: Well, the only solution that comes in my mind is using javascript.

Comment: That is fine with me.

Comment: I managed to find it out on my own: $(window).scroll(function(){
    $('#menu-wrapper').css({
        'top': $(this).scrollTop()
    });
});

But I'll accept your answer for leading me in the right direction. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Sure no problem. I was editing the answer. Anyway, get a look at the edit covered the scenario that user doesn't have activated javascript (the content will disappear under navigation - best scenario). Sorry for the late edit, I had to step out for a few minutes.

Comment: Thanks man. It works great in firefox. It also works in chrome and IE. But when I scroll up and down, the #menu-wrapper jumps and shakes quite a bit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45231/discussion-between-dragos-rizescu-and-adnaves)